# Word VBA: Why is my "export as pdf, accept all changes, and save as" macro accepting the changes at the wrong time?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a macro to save a .pdf copy of "[document name]-changes", which shows all tracked changes, then accepts all the changes and saves a .docx copy of "[document name]-edited". The exporting all works and the files are named correctly, but the .pdf copy has already had all changes accepted and doesn't show any changes, even though ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll doesn't come until after the .pdf has been created. Anybody know why this is happening?

Code:

```
Sub ExportAndSave()


Dim CurrentFolder As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim myPath As String


'Store Information About Word File
  myPath = ActiveDocument.FullName
  CurrentFolder = ActiveDocument.Path & "\"
  FileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, _
   InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)

  
'Export PDF as [filename]-changes

   ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    OutputFileName:=FileName & "-changes", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
     
     
'Accept changes and save as [filename]-edited

   ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll
   ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=FileName & "-edited"
     

End Sub
```

Cheers

Comment: Do you see revisions in the pdf if you comment out the `AcceptAll`?

Comment: As https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-word-2010-why-do-my-red-track-changes-convert/cc0db045-80f4-4571-8a03-8f5f25a22a90 suggests, you should pass [`Item:=wdExportDocumentWithMarkup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat#parameters) to your `ExportAsFixedFormat`.

Comment: @GSerg managed to add ExportWithMarkup without an error, but getting the same issue. Current code is the same, but with `, _` at the end of `ExportFormat` line, and `Item:=wdExportDocumentWithMarkup` on the next line

Comment: @GSerg sorted it and posted the answer below - cheers for the push in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Needed to save as PDF with `SaveAs2` rather than exporting. Also forgot to add `CurrentFolder` to the file name so it was going straight to My Documents as default.

```
Sub ExportAndSave()


Dim CurrentFolder As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim myPath As String


'Store Information About Word File
  myPath = ActiveDocument.FullName
  CurrentFolder = ActiveDocument.Path & "\"
  FileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, _
   InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)

  
'Export PDF as [filename]-changes
   
   ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=CurrentFolder & FileName & "-changes", _
   FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
     
'Accept changes and save as [filename]-edited

   ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll
   ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=CurrentFolder & FileName & "-edited"
     

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is:

```
Sub ExportAndSave()
Dim StrNm As String
With ActiveDocument
  StrNm = Split(.FullName, ".doc")(0)
  .SaveAs FileName:=StrNm & "-changes.pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  .Revisions.AcceptAll
  .SaveAs FileName:=StrNm & "-edited.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
End Sub
```